# Facebook login not working with FB official app installed on phone

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am building an app, which is going to have support for `FaceBook`.
The problem is with login.If original `FaceBook` app is not installed on phone, 
the login is going through custom dialog and everything works fine,
but if official `FaceBook` app is installed, the login is going through custom dialog and 
automatically redirect to original `FaceBook` app, and then nothing happened.
I have tested this on different phones, and always was the same problem.Below is my code,

```
public class Login extends Activity {

public static final String mAPP_ID = getString(R.string.APP_ID);
public Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(mAPP_ID);
String cus_id, cus_mob, cus_name, cus_points, success,fb_id;
SessionManager session;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.LoginButton)).setOnClickListener(loginButtonListener);
    SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private OnClickListener loginButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authorizing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mFacebook.authorize(Login.this, new String[] { "" },
                    new LoginDialogListener());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Has valid session",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me"));
                String facebookID = json.getString("id");
                String firstName = json.getString("first_name");
                String lastName = json.getString("last_name");
                Toast.makeText(
                        Login.this,
                        "You already have a valid session, " + firstName
                                + " " + lastName
                                + ". No need to re-authorize.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Userpage1.class);
                startActivity(in);

            } catch (Exception error) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FacebookError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
};

public final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        try {
            // The user has logged in, so now you can query and use their
            // Facebook info
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me"));
            String facebookID = json.getString("id");
            String firstName = json.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = json.getString("last_name");
            Toast.makeText(
                    Login.this,
                    "Thank you for Logging In, " + firstName + " "
                            + lastName + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            SessionStore.save(mFacebook, Login.this);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fb_id", facebookID));
            String response = null;
            try {
                response = LoginHttpClient
                        .executeHttpPost(
                                "http://10.0.2.2/Upshot_Loyalty_Program/android_api/get_fb_id.php",
                                postParameters);
                JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jArray = json1.getJSONArray("customer");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    success = json_data.getString("success");
                    cus_id = json_data.getString("cus_id");
                    cus_name = json_data.getString("cus_name");
                    cus_points = json_data.getString("cus_points");
                    // User_List.add(json_data.getString("cus_id"));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (success.equals("1")) {
                session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
                session.createLoginSessionRemMe(cus_id, cus_name,
                        cus_points);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Userpage1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Mobileno.class);
                i.putExtra("fb_id", facebookID);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception error) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } catch (FacebookError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

      }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @anirudhmaddy problem slove by myself. check hashkey process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it in the following way. Due to Facebook Android SDK documentation: every Android app you'll create will be signed, and you will **need to register each app's key hash with Facebook as a security check for authenticity**. To bypass this check for your application, you must add your key hash to your Facebook Developer profile.

To generate your key hash on your local computer, run Java's keytool utility (which should be on your console's path) against the Android keystore (debug keystore during development, release for production). For DEBUG keystore on Windows run:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Then go to your developer settings on Facebook, select your application from the nav on the left, and add and save your key hash into your profile. You will now be able to run your app successfully.

For more detailed description please follow: [Facebook Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) and start reading from the paragraph "Put simply, every Android app you'll create will be signed, and you will need to register each app's key ..."